# Trap OID to trap name - snmp

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp, snmp-trap

There is a set of snmp trap OID's, from different vendor devices like Cisco/Juniper/Arista etc...

For example: 1.3.6.1.4.1.6101.1.8.8.2.1

We would like to know the trap names for each OID. There are more than 300 OID's.

---

Programmatically we store all trap OID's in set, using python.

What is the best approach to retrieve trap names? Does any public repository provide mapping of trap OID to trap name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the [mibbuild.py --destination-format json](http://snmplabs.com/pysmi/mibdump.html) tool over all your MIBs. You will get one JSON document for each of your MIB files. The JSON documents will look [like this](http://mibs.snmplabs.com/json/notexts/):

```
"coldStart": {
  "name": "coldStart", 
  "oid": "1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1", 
  "class": "notificationtype", 
  "status": "current"
},
```

From here you can load JSON into Python, create a new `dict` like `{json[key]['oid']: key for key in json}` which you could use for looking up TRAP names by OID.

If your collection of MIBs is changing and needs constant updates, you can build the above procedure into your application by calling [pysmi](https://github.com/etingof/pysmi) functions.

EDIT:

If you need to resolve whatever TRAP OID into its MIB name, you can grab as many MIBs as you can find on the Internet and run the above procedure over them. However you still may not be able to resolve all TRAP OIDs you encounter in the wild. It is more typical to have MIBs for all the devices your software is managing.

The default for the `mibdump` tool is to pull requested MIBs from http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/ site.

Comment: Am sorry.. I donot have list of mibs that hold the definition of these traps.... Can't I rely on some public repository to access all MIBS?

Comment: Does mibbuild rely on sme public source of mibs?

Comment: There are some mib OIDS coming that are non-vendor like CA sysedge traps for syslogs... I understand your point...

Comment: Well, regardless of the source of the TRAP, the only way to get hold of OID semantics (including its name) is to look it up in a MIB....

Comment: I got hold of mib files that are located in folder and its subfolders... what would be the syntax to use mibbuild to pick all mib files from all subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

1.3.6.1.4.1.6101.1.8.8.2.1==>

1.3.6.1.4.1. == ...private enterprise (worth memorizing)

6101 == private.enterprise number for Trend Micro Inc., these #s are maintained at https://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers/enterprise-numbers

1.8.8.2.1 == will need to get the MIB, ideally directly from Trend Micro, Inc.

--Obviously, you'll need to load all the MIBs you need to decode for python to work.  MIBs can reference other MIBs too, so it can get messy.  I've always just done it manually, so I can't speak about any tools to do this.   But I did not need to do much with SNMP.  Your situation could be different.